# How to auto search list in android custom list view?

Tags: android, listview

In my application I have use custom list and data are come from web service, now I want to add functionality to auto search list like [this auto complete example](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-autocomplete.html).

Comment: This question is too broad, and has only attracted one low-quality answer in several years. I think it should be put on hold.

Answer (score -1):

You can see in that link which you gave. It have solution for it. You just want to now store this data into string array which can be given to adapter for autocompletetextview.